# Number of {0,1}-matrices with an even number of 1’s in each row vs in each column

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, 0-1-matrices

I am working on an equation that would be solved if I show the following.

Let $k \geq l$, and consider the set of $\{0,1\}$-matrices of size $k \times l$ with exactly $i$ 1’s. Consider the subset $\mathcal{A}_i$ of such matrices with an even number of 1’s in each *row*, and consider the subset $\mathcal{B}_i$ of such matrices with an even number of 1’s in each *column*. If $i \leq k \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor - 1$, then $|\mathcal{A}_i| \leq |\mathcal{B}_i|$.

Is it an already known result? If yes, I have not found it in the litterature. If not, I’ll try to work on a proof!

**EDIT** The strategy written in the comment is great. I can come up with a solution using these generating functions. This gives a numerical solution. Is there exists a proof using an injection from $\mathcal{A}_i$ to $\mathcal{B}_i$?

Comment: Using a standard generating function argument, I got $\mathcal{A}_{i}$ as the $i$-th coefficient of $(\frac{1}{2}\cdot((1+x)^{l}+(1-x)^{l}))^{k}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{i}$ as the $i$-th coefficient of $(\frac{1}{2}\cdot((1+x)^{k}+(1-x)^{k}))^{l}$. Furthermore, if $\mu$ is a probability measure and $f,g$ are measurable, then $\|f\|_{l}\leq\|g\|_{k}$ whenever $1\leq l\leq k<\infty$, so one gets the inequality $(\frac{a^{l}+b^{l}}{2})^{k}\leq(\frac{a^{k}+b^{k}}{2})^{l}$ whenever $a,b\geq 0$. This is similar to what we want.